# Vue component name must be lowercase?

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to use a component in my view file. The following doesn't work
When I try to mount the component in my view with `<CampaignCreate></CampaignCreate>`

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#rewards-app',
    components: {
       CampaignCreate,
    }
});
```

If I change it to:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#rewards-app',
    components: {
       'campaign-create': CampaignCreate,
    }
});
```

I can mount the component in my view file as `<campaign-create></campaign-create>` without a problem. I am trying to understand the reason behind this. I am currently on vuejs 2.x

Comment: Thank's @raina77ow that explains it.

Comment: It's also because native custom elements must be named all lower case and contain a dash.

Comment: Yeah go ahead @raina77ow

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In short, it's because HTML is case-insensitive. There was [a big discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2308) in VueJS tracker opened 2 years ago by Evan You himself with the following reasoning:

> So as we all know, HTML is case insensitive. `myProp="123"` gets parsed
>   as `myprop="123"` and this has led to the caveat in Vue.js where you
>   have to use `my-prop="123"` to refer to a prop declared in JavaScript as
>   `myProp`. This bites beginners quite often.

The issue was eventually closed with decision to stay on the same track. Here's a telling quote:

> Essentially, the problem exists because js and html are different
>   technologies and use different naming systems. And using same
>   case(kebab or camel) in both technologies will shift weirdness from
>   one place to another but the underlying problem will persist So I
>   believe, best we can do is draw a line. and the current line i,e.
>   kebab case in html context and camelCase (and PascalCase) in js
>   context is very good.

Comment: seriously? This kind of things should be put in the front page of Vue JS..., quoted, framed, highlighted! damx... I just wasted 1.5 hr on this one.

Comment: The worse part is that its still like this in Vue3 and their example has upper case characters and it doesn't work.

Comment: I think that VUE's bundle could very easily include a case check and warn the user if a component is using `myProp` and `myprop`. This way users can be directed to the quote above.