# Vue.js - Single file component - Unknown custom element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I got a simple single-file component called "`MobileApps.vue`":

```
<template>
    <div class="grey-bg about-page">
        <p>{{ greetings }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Home',
        data() {
            return {
                greetings: "Hello"
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

And registering it:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
components: {
    Home,
    About,
    Gas,
    Electricity,
    Contacts,
    Electricity_info,
    Gas_info,
    MobileApps
},
data: {
},
created() {
},
destroyed() {

},
mounted() {
    let mySVGsToInject = document.querySelectorAll('img.inject-me');
    SVGInjector(mySVGsToInject);
},
methods: {
}
```

});

When I'm trying to open the HTML file with `<MobileApps>` component I'll get an error:

> vue.esm.js:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

But even when I provide a name, nothing happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue component name must be lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085622/vue-component-name-must-be-lowercase)

Comment: @underscore_d nope.

Comment: Weird, because you accepted an answer that indicates you had the same root cause, as far as I can read.

Comment: @underscore_d Sry, my bad. Your right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with cabeb-case format  `<mobile-apps>` like :

```
 <mobile-apps></mobile-apps>
```